# Buttons getting chopped off with flex-direction: column

Tags: css, flexbox

I was trying to make a chat UI with some actions that show in an overlay, but the buttons got chopped off. Here's what I tried to do:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #111;
  color: white;
}
.overlay {
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque sit odio temporibus quidem, tempora libero nobis fuga impedit alias illum.
  <div class="overlay">
    <button>
      A
    </button>
    <button>
      B
    </button>
    <button>
      C
    </button>
    <button>
      D
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking for something that looks like a grid, and would get longer if more buttons were added.
If I set `flex-direction` to row instead, it works fine, but that makes the buttons not be stacked. If I remove `overflow: hidden` I can see the buttons outside of the overlay, instead of it staying inside of the box. If I set a width for the overlay, things work fine, but I want the width to be dynamic.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for if you already know 3 answers to your problem?

Comment: The first one makes the buttons the full height. The second one has them clipping out of the box, which looks bad. The third one is fixed, instead of fitting the area of the buttons.

Comment: what do you want it to look like?

Comment: edited the question with more details

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

What I did was made the parent container `display: flex;` so it will expand to the size of the child div `.overlay`, then simply made the overlay a grid with only 1 column in order to have the buttons in 1 column.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: #111;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.overlay {
  background: purple;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque sit odio temporibus quidem, tempora libero nobis fuga impedit alias illum.
  <div class="overlay">
    <button>
      A
    </button>
    <button>
      B
    </button>
    <button>
      C
    </button>
    <button>
      D
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: ok maybe this is what you want?

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #111;
  color: white;
}
.overlay {
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque sit odio temporibus quidem, tempora libero nobis fuga impedit alias illum.
  <div class="overlay">
    <button>
      A
    </button>
    <button>
      B
    </button>
    <button>
      C
    </button>
    <button>
      D
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

OK last edit then im giving up if this isn't it:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #111;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}
.overlay {
  background: purple;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque sit odio temporibus quidem, tempora libero nobis fuga impedit alias illum.' 
  <div class="overlay">
    <button>
      A
    </button>
    <button>
      B
    </button>
    <button>
      C
    </button>
    <button>
      D
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not quite what I was looking for; the overlay is supposed to *overlay* the content, and wrap if needed

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. :/

Comment: @KTibow I think i might get it now.  I have updated my answer. please look and let me know

Comment: it still seems to cut off the C and D buttons

Comment: Ok I edited my code 1 more time. please look

Comment: I mean that works; however in this case I would rather the text go on as before, given this is a menu not shown by default. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Ok, well good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `parent` a fixed height, based on the height of the buttons. For example if I try: `height: 100px;` then I can see the buttons just fine as a vertical grid to the right of the text.[image: Grid vertical CSS]

Comment: that works, but if you add more buttons it overflows, and I would rather the parent be as tall as the content

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container{
display:flex;}

#x, #y{
display:flex;}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque sit odio temporibus quidem, tempora libero nobis fuga impedit alias illum.
</div>
<div>
  <div id='x'>
    <button>
      A
    </button>
    <button>
      B
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id='y'>
    <button>
      C
    </button>
    <button>
      D
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that works, i'll probably end up using grid

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work with grid:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #111;
  color: white;
}
.overlay {
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque sit odio temporibus quidem, tempora libero nobis fuga impedit alias illum.
  <div class="overlay">
    <button>
      A
    </button>
    <button>
      B
    </button>
    <button>
      C
    </button>
    <button>
      D
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex can do it.

Make three minor adjustments to your CSS code. (No changes to HTML.)

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  /*  overflow: hidden; */ /* 1 */
  background: #111;
  color: white;
}

.overlay {
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column; */ /* 2  */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

button {
  flex-basis: 50%; /* 3 */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque sit odio temporibus quidem, tempora libero nobis fuga impedit alias illum.
  <div class="overlay">
    <button>
      A
    </button>
    <button>
      B
    </button>
    <button>
      C
    </button>
    <button>
      D
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```